# Is using nested spans in HTML 5 valid?

Tags: html, validation

Is it standard in HTML 5 if we use span in span?

```
<span class="fake-input">
  <span id="fake-input"></span>
  <span id="deftext">No file selectedspan</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I haven't found a reference specifically for HTML 5, but this StackOverflow question says that they are OK in XHTML: [Are nested span tags OK in XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078127/are-nested-span-tags-ok-in-xhtml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a job for a div:

```
<div class="fake-input">
  <span id="fake-input"></span>
  <span id="deftext">No file selectedspan</span>
</div>
```

If you wanted to take that further, you might be using `<form>` tags, `<input>` tags, etc, but that's going further off topic.

Divs and spans have no semantic value or automatic styles; they're there for you to assign this to them. However, commonly you'd use divs for block elements, and spans for inline elements.

You won't get a validation error, but I don't see nested spans much these days.

Comment: thanks for the answer, normally i don't use nested span either but i'm using pre-built template and i don't want go to all css files for a small change :). as long as it's valid i'm fine with it :D

Comment: @mafortis Gotcha. Yes, it's valid. In fact, if you take some HTML5 boilerplate, plug the code into the body, and run it through a validator, it won't flag anything.

Answer (score 37):

Nesting span tags is valid HTML.

A span tag is non-semantic markup intended for grouping inline content, and is a [valid wrapper for phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content). This includes tags like `strong`, `em`, `time`, and etc, but also additional `span` tags.

You can confirm this by pasting the following code into the [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Nested Spans Test</title></head>
<body>

<span class="fake-input">
    <span id="fake-input"></span>
    <span id="deftext">No file selectedspan</span>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, keep in mind that valid HTML [isn't as big a deal as you might think](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/858990753909022720), as invalid HTML is unlikely to effect SEO rank or page display, so long as the markup can be parsed.

In a case like this, with a faux inputs being built out of `<span>` tags, a much bigger concern should be accessibility and I would recommend looking into [including proper `aria-` attributes](https://w3c.github.io/using-aria) that expose the relationships and functionality of these elements to anyone using a screen reader or who isn't viewing them with your custom styles.